# Magento 2 Attempt to load value of nonexistent EAV attribute with CategoryInterface

Tags: magento-2.1.7, log, eav-attributes

I am getting error as following in my System.log file.

Attempt to load value of nonexistent EAV attribute '42'
                        for entity type 'Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\CategoryInterface'

I have checked this [Magento 2 Attempt to load value of nonexistent EAV attribute](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/173218/magento-2-attempt-to-load-value-of-nonexistent-eav-attribute). It is product related. but my is Category related.

How to solve this error?

Comment: ,can you found any solution for this error. i did like this- Actually i deleted some custom attribute using code as well as manually from backend after this i got this error in log/system.xml

Answer (score 1):

## Not to be confused with

Entity type `Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface`

This is specifically a `Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\CategoryInterface` issue. So we are dealing with different tables:

- catalog_category_entity_datetime
- catalog_category_entity_decimal
- catalog_category_entity_int
- catalog_category_entity_text
- catalog_category_entity_varchar

Rather than equivalent *catalog_product_entity_* *

## Prerequisites

This is an attribute that no longer exists, you should get this error when trying to load in */admin/catalog/product_attribute/edit/attribute_id/42/*

> This attribute no longer exists.

## Solution

The following queries *should* reveal old references to this non-existent attribute:

```
SELECT * FROM catalog_category_entity_datetime WHERE attribute_id = 42;
SELECT * FROM catalog_category_entity_decimal WHERE attribute_id = 42;
SELECT * FROM catalog_category_entity_int WHERE attribute_id = 42;
SELECT * FROM catalog_category_entity_text WHERE attribute_id = 42;
SELECT * FROM catalog_category_entity_varchar WHERE attribute_id = 42;
```

Whichever of these tables reveal the old reference we need to delete:

```
DELETE FROM catalog_category_entity_<WHICHEVER> WHERE attribute_id = 42;
```

BAM, I hope the error no longer appears

Answer (score 0):

After remove eav_attribute, you need to remove from catalog_eav_attribute 
Hope it will work for you.

Comment: ,i did both things but even this error is showing.