# Error in system.log magento 2

Tags: magento2, attributes, error

Can anyone help me with this error

```
main.WARNING: Attempt to load value of nonexistent EAV attribute '161'
                        for entity type 'Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface'. [] []
```

please help

Thanks.

Comment: This might be helpful https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/173218/magento-2-attempt-to-load-value-of-nonexistent-eav-attribute

Comment: i checked with this query SELECT * FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `attribute_id` = 161. but it gives empty result

Comment: you are migrate after showing this error ??

Comment: Check in catalog_eav_attribute table, SELECT * FROM `catalog_eav_attribute` WHERE `attribute_id` = 161, delete that entry

Comment: No, i have added one module yesterday mageplaza better popuu. after that this error is coming and my checkout page does not load. i removed this module completely still the issue persist.

Comment: @YashPatadia yes i find thr, are you sure, i should delete it

Comment: take a backup of that table and delete

Comment: how to take backup of single table?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682916/how-to-take-backup-of-a-single-table-in-a-mysql-database, mysqldump -u <db_username> -h <db_host> -p db_name table_name > table_name.sql

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105634/discussion-between-nafisa-and-yash-patadia).